# Unable to get JQuery-Mobile collapsible expand/collapse event to execute

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have the following demo HTML file that I am tying to use the JQuery-Mobile collapsible expand/collapse events and I am not able to get the JavaScript event to fire.  I am basing this off the JSFiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/6txWy/

I feel like I am just overlooking something simple but here is my HTML file:

```
<html> 
<head> 
  <title>References</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>  

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#my-collaspible').bind('expand', function()
  {
    alert('Expanded');
  }).bind('collapse', function () {
    alert('Collapsed');
  });
  </script>
</head> 

<body>
  <div data-role="page">
      <div data-role="content">
          <div data-role="collapsible" id="my-collaspible">
              <h3>My Title</h3>
              <p>My Body</p>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The collapse and expand work but the alerts are never fired.

Thanks!
Flea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a [PageInit](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html) call to make sure the page is loaded before binding the events

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/UT7kQ/

Code:

```
$('#home').live('pageinit', function(event) {
    $('#my-collaspible').bind('expand', function() {
        alert('Expanded');
    }).bind('collapse', function() {
        alert('Collapsed');
    });
});
```