# Expand/Collapse Div with Jquery loading in head

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am using the latest jquery build (ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js) and have the script linked in the head part of the page, because I have other functions that require it to be there. 
I am trying to use a simple expand/collapse function added to the head part of the document to expand content contained in a FOREACH statement.

I found this [Unable to get JQuery-Mobile collapsible expand/collapse event to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819817/unable-to-get-jquery-mobile-collapsible-expand-collapse-event-to-execute) which works in the fiddle example from one of the answers: http://jsfiddle.net/UT7kQ/ but when I change the script in the head to the newest version of jquery, it doesn't work.

This is the code I'm trying to use in the head section to expand/collapse the content contained in a FOREACH statement:

```
$('.info').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.hide').toggle();
});
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in the old [$('document').ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Answer (score 3):

Try using `.on` instead of `.live`. Go to `api.jquery.com` and look at `.live`; it was deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9.

You may also need to wrap this in a `$(document).ready(function(){});` statement. Otherwise jQuery may run without the dom element being in the page. If it doesn't find the element when it runs, nothing will happen or it will cause errors.

Comment: Thank you! I used the $(document).ready(function(){}); and it fixed it.